# how to configure jEdit to select $ along with variable name

Tags: php, jedit

How do I set up jEdit to pick up the dollar sign as part of the variable name when selecting a "word" in php mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jEdit 4.3pre14, open the Global Options from the Utilities menu. Select Editing from the tree and add $ to Extra Word Characters and apply the changes. You can either apply this change to all editing modes or only php.